# Merging Tables in Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My Excel doc grabs information from outside files and stores them in 5 separate sheets/tables.Each table has the same columns and ordering, but the amount of rows varies day-to-day.

What I've been trying to do is merge all the data into one table. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than my Copy/Paste code below?

*This is only code for 2 tables. There are a total of 5 tables that I want to combine.*

```
Sub merge()
Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm")
Dim masterWS As Worksheet:  Set masterWS = wb.Worksheets("MASTER")
Dim WS1 As Worksheet:     Set WS1 = wb.Worksheets("1")
Dim WS2 As Worksheet:    Set WS2 = wb.Worksheets("2")
Dim WS3 As Worksheet:    Set WS3 = wb.Worksheets("3")
Dim WS4 As Worksheet:    Set WS4 = wb.Worksheets("4")
Dim WS5 As Worksheet:     Set WS5 = wb.Worksheets("5")

Dim counter1 As Long
Dim counter2 As Long
Dim counter3 As Long
Dim counter4 As Long
Dim counter5 As Long
Dim counter As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Count rows for each account
WS1.Activate
counter1 = WS1.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
WS2.Activate
counter2 = WS2.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
WS3.Activate
counter3 = WS3.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
WS4.Activate
counter4 = WS4.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
WS5.Activate
counter5 = WS5.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

' Sum of counter
counter = counter1 + counter2 + counter3 + counter4 + counter5

While counter > 0
    If counter1 > 0 Then
        counter = counter - counter1
        WS1.Range("E11:E" & counter1 + 10).Copy 
        masterWS.Range("B:B" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("I11:I" & counter1 + 10).Copy
        masterWS.Range("C:C" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("J11:J" & counter1 + 10).Copy
        masterWS.Range("D:D" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("K11:K" & counter1 + 10).Copy 
        masterWS.Range("E:E" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("S11:S" & counter1 + 10).Copy 'BROKER
        masterWS.Range("F:F" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("B11:B" & counter1 + 10).Copy 'TD
        masterWS.Range("G:G" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS1.Range("C11:C" & counter1 + 10).Copy 'SD
        masterWS.Range("H:H" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        masterWS.Range("I:I" & counter).Value = "TEST"

    End If

    If counter2 > 0 Then
        counter = counter - counter2
        WS2.Range("E11:E" & counter2 + 10).Copy 
        masterWS.Range("B:B" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("I11:I" & counter2 + 10).Copy 
        masterWS.Range("C:C" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("J11:J" & counter2 + 10).Copy 'AMOUNT
        masterWS.Range("D:D" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("K11:K" & counter2 + 10).Copy 'PRICE
        masterWS.Range("E:E" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("S11:S" & counter2 + 10).Copy 'BROKER
        masterWS.Range("F:F" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("B11:B" & counter2 + 10).Copy 'TD
        masterWS.Range("G:G" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        WS2.Range("C11:C" & counter2 + 10).Copy 'SD
        masterWS.Range("H:H" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        masterWS.Range("I:I" & counter).Value = "test2"


    End If
Wend





Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How does this compile at all? VBA shouldn't let you name variables starting with numbers.  Also, you would just want to loop (through worksheets/tables/etc) and there are myriad resources online to help with that.

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry about the variables - I had to change them in Stackoverflow because my variables contained private info. I can update that.

Comment: `counter1 = 1WS.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` here `Range("A11").End(xlDown)` will always operate on the *activesheet*, which may not be the sheet you want if 1WS is not active.  Always qualify Range()/Cells() with a worksheet reference.

Comment: @TimWilliams I activate each sheet before the counter.

Comment: Better to write your code so you don't need to do that.

Comment: have you considered using M instead of VBA? if you use Excel newer than 2007 it's probably the most efficient way, see sample here
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-files-in-a-folder-with-Combine-Binaries-Power-Query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4

Comment: @Stachu I haven't heard of M, but I'll definitely look into it. Does it provide the same functionalities of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a loop to handle this. Initialize a list of the worksheets you want to do copy/paste code with, then iterate over those worksheets.

```
Dim WSArray As Variant
Dim currentWS As Worksheet
WSArray = Array("WSName1", "WSName2", "WSName3", "WSName4", "WSName5")

For Each currentWSName In WSArray
    Set currentWS = wb.Worksheets(currentWSName)
    ' Copy Pasted Code Goes here, but reference currentWS instead of WS1 etc
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This will definitely organize the code a bit more. The issue I still am running into is having the data not overlap in the main table. I'll try to work with the code more and see if i can try to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successful make this work. The code below takes data from 5 separate tables on different sheets and stores them in one table.

```
        ' -- Merges sheets to one table -- '
    Sub merge()
        Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm")
        Dim masterWS As Worksheet:  Set masterWS = wb.Worksheets("MASTER")
        Dim WS1 As Worksheet:     Set WS1 = wb.Worksheets("1")
        Dim WS2 As Worksheet:    Set WS2 = wb.Worksheets("2")
        Dim WS3 As Worksheet:    Set WS3 = wb.Worksheets("3")
        Dim WS4 As Worksheet:    Set WS4 = wb.Worksheets("4")
        Dim WS5 As Worksheet:     Set WS5 = wb.Worksheets("5")
        Dim WSArray As Variant
        Dim currentWS As Worksheet

        Dim counter1 As Long
        Dim counter2 As Long
        Dim counter3 As Long
        Dim counter4 As Long
        Dim counter5 As Long
        Dim counter As Long
        Dim tempCounter As Long

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ' Count rows for each account
        WS1.Activate
        counter1 = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("1").Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        WS2.Activate
        counter2 = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("2").Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        WS3.Activate
        counter3 = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("3").Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        WS4.Activate
        counter4 = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("4").Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        WS5.Activate
        counter5 = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsm").Worksheets("5").Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        ' Sum of counter
        counter = counter1 + counter2 + counter3 + counter4 + counter5 + 2

        WSArray = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

        For Each currentWSName In WSArray
            Set currentWS = wb.Worksheets(currentWSName)

            currentWS.Activate

            If IsEmpty(currentWS.Range("A12").Value) = True And IsEmpty(currentWS.Range("A11")) = False Then
                tempCounter = 1
            Else
                tempCounter = currentWS.Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
            End If


            counter = (counter - tempCounter)

            If IsEmpty(currentWS.Range("A11").Value) = False Then
                currentWS.Range("E11:E" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'ISIN
                masterWS.Range("B" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("I11:I" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'B/S
                masterWS.Range("C" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("J11:J" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'AMOUNT
                masterWS.Range("D" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("K11:K" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'PRICE
                masterWS.Range("E" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("S11:S" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'BROKER
                masterWS.Range("F" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("B11:B" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'TD
                masterWS.Range("G" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                currentWS.Range("C11:C" & tempCounter + 10).Copy 'SD
                masterWS.Range("H" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

                masterWS.Range("I" & counter & ":I" & (tempCounter + counter) - 1).Value = currentWSName
            End If

            Next currentWSName



        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```